# An Excel sheet that will have 2-3k columns and 100 rows, is it better to use vlookup/hlookup or index/match from an efficiency/size perspective?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Thinking about sheet design and unfortunately, it looks like it's going to have a lot of rows and columns that will have to be looking up values. From a size/speed/efficiency perspective, is it better to use index/match in the formulas or VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP?

thanks so much!

Comment: Sounds like a database would be better.  As to your question: This has been debated a lot: https://www.defeatexcel.com/vlookup-vs-index-match

Comment: Instead of limiting yourself to formulas available in excel 2007-2010, what about getting a free microsoft account so you can use the web version of excel. Perhaps there are new formulas that can more readily solve your problem.

Comment: Time to upgrade to a proper database I think

Comment: A database is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDEX-MATCH is **always** faster from a size/speed perspective. VLOOKUP is simpler, so more time efficient to put together (or fix) a small report

Example differences from [exceluser.com](https://exceluser.com/702/why-index-match-is-far-better-than-vlookup-or-hlookup-in-excel/), using a small dataset, but hundreds of loops. The speed difference will increase as you add more data:

> With unsorted data, VLOOKUP and INDEX-MATCH have about the same calculation times. That is, INDEX-MATCH is only about 3% faster.
>
> With sorted data and an approximate match, INDEX-MATCH is about 30% faster than VLOOKUP.
>
> With sorted data and a fast technique to find an exact match, INDEX-MATCH is about 13% faster than VLOOKUP.

But after certain complexity limits, it's better to reformat the data in a separate step, create a better data model, improve the import, or work in VBA